# Matlibplot not opening any graph or window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've searched through related questions and most say there is something wrong with the backend.  I've checked if there are any GUI libraries that matplotlib can use on my laptop and there are.  Even after trying to replace the backend within the code, nothing pops up.  Is there a way to permanently switch the backend or change it within the code in a way that works.  I'm using python 3.6 and IDLE.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

pp.rcParams["backend"] = "Qt4Agg"
import sys

m1=float(input("m1:"))
m2=float(input("m2:"))
data=[[3,1.5,1],
      [2,1,0],
      [4,1.5,1],
      [3,1,0],
      [3.5,.5,0],
      [2,.5,0],
      [5.5,1,1],
      [1,1,0]]
unkknown=[4.5,1]
#Net
w1=numpy.random.randn()
w2=numpy.random.randn()
b=numpy.random.randn()
T=numpy.linspace(-5,5,10)
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+numpy.exp(-x))
Y=sigmoid(T)
pp.plot(T,Y)
def cost(b):
    return (b-4)**4
def slope(b):
    return 2*(b-4)
def NN(m1,m2,w1,w2,b):
    z=m1*w1+w2*m1+b
    return sigmoid(z)

b=b-.1*slope(b)

print(NN(m1,m2,w1,w2,b))
pp.plot(T,Y)
pp.show
```

Comment: It should be `pp.show()`, not `pp.show`.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to put the parentheses after `show`.

[image]

Just in case, I've modified code a bit

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import sys

def cost(b):
    return (b-4)**4

def slope(b):
    return 2*(b-4)

def NN(m1,m2,w1,w2,b):
    z=m1*w1+w2*m1+b
    return sigmoid(z)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+numpy.exp(-x))

m1=float(input("m1:"))
m2=float(input("m2:"))

data=[[3,1.5,1],
      [2,1,0],
      [4,1.5,1],
      [3,1,0],
      [3.5,.5,0],
      [2,.5,0],
      [5.5,1,1],
      [1,1,0]]

unkknown=[4.5,1]
#Net
w1=numpy.random.randn()
w2=numpy.random.randn()
b=numpy.random.randn()
T=numpy.linspace(-5,5,10)
Y=sigmoid(T)

b=b -.1 * slope(b)

print(NN(m1,m2,w1,w2,b))
pp.plot(T,Y)
pp.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pp.show()
```

Does the trick, as we're calling a function.